# Tree recursive function time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Why is the complexity of this code θ(N^2 log N)?

```
def f(n):
  if n == 0:
    return
  else:
    f(n//2)
    f(n//2)
    f(n//2)
    f(n//2)
    g(n)    //runs in θ(n^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply [Master Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))(refer to case 2->case2a) you would see that  T(n)=4T(n/2)+n^2 we see that
ccrit = log2(4) = 2 = c, f(n)=g(n)=(n^(ccrit))*log^k(n) => k=0,k>(-1) => then T(n)=Theta((n^ccrit)*log^(k+1)n)=Theta(N^2* log N).

Expanded explanation: you are recursing 4 times on subproblems of n/2 hence a=4,b=2, since g(n) is O(n^2) then c=2 since ccrit=c case 1 and 3 do not apply we see that (n^(ccrit))*log^k(n) indeed is equal to n^2 if k=0 and that satisfies case 2.